# How to containerize laravel and postgres using docker?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Please help with code for dockerfile and docker-compose file i need laravel setup and postgres.

This is my docker file

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        graphviz \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_psql \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8000
```

this is docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  php_4:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres_4

  postgres_4:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: lara_4
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
```

Both are not working giving different different errors. SO please anyone give fresh code for both dockerfile and docker-compose file for laravel with postgresql using docker.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify web server, i.e. nginx in docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Is this not possible without using nginx ???

Comment: possible, but it is cleaner and easier to declare it in .yml file
For troubleshooting please provide error details

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) if you're just starting out with Laravel + Docker.

For your question in general, please edit your question and insert the specific errors.

Comment: Need my own services. so i didnt go for sail. laravel with mysql is working very fine but need more information and clarification in laravel using postgres.

Comment: Then we need more information, please supply the errors.